# UIViewController localization problem (duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, localization, xcode4

I have too much problem with the localization process in XCode4:

After I localize a UIViewController with the File Inspector and add French and English for example, I always got some errors that said that the Instance or file are duplicated, e.g.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_....
```

Any idea for one of the 2 problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xcode localisation feature duplicates a given file and places each copy in the corresponding language directory (.lproj). This makes sense for resources (nib files, text files) that are language-dependent but you should not do this for classes. Otherwise, you end up having the same class defined twice in your code, hence the duplicate symbols.

What you should do instead is to use `NSLocalizedString…` in your implementation files, extract the strings with `genstrings`, and place the translations in the corresponding language directories.

I suggest you read the [Internationalization Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) guide written by Apple. Matt Gallagher recently wrote a post about [user interface strings in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/04/user-interface-strings-in-cocoa.html); you might want to read it as well.

Comment: I already knew that before. I just don't understand why they didn't block the functionality in the File Inspector for classes. Thats why I thought it was possible that way. Then I will do it like you said. Thank you~

Comment: @ludo You could [file a bug report with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) asking for Xcode not to enable localisation of implementation files. That’s an odd behaviour, indeed.

Comment: ans you you know about this error when I localize xib file : 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle

Comment: @ludo It looks like the nib file hasn’t been placed correctly in the bundle when you built the application. Check if you have a copy of every localised nib file in the language (.lproj) directories.